# Having problem with changing background color of a selected option in react-select

Tags: react-select

I'm currently using react-select to style a search bar within my project, and most aspects are functioning as expected. However, I'm encountering an issue with altering the color of selected options within the dropdown menu.

As for the setup, I have configured the dropdown to remain open until the user manually closes it by clicking the closing arrow. Additionally, I've enabled the multi-choice option. Here's where I'm seeking assistance: I want the background color of an already selected option to change after it's been chosen.

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { useState } from 'react';
import './CSS/NavBar.css';

export default function SearchBar(props) {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);

  const songOptions = Object.keys(props.songs).map((songKey) => {
    const { artist, song, img } = props.songs[songKey];
  return {
    value: `${artist} - ${song}`,
    label: `${artist} - ${song}`,
    image: img,
  };
})
;

      const customOption = ({ innerProps, label, data, isSelected }) => (
        <div {...innerProps} className={isSelected ? 'custom-option selected' : 'custom-option'}>
          <img src={data.image} alt="Singer Picture" className="navImage" />
          <span className='song-label'>{label}</span>
        </div>
      );

      const customStyles = { 
        control: (styles) => ({ ...styles, backgroundColor: "pink", color: "black" }),
        option: (provided, state) => ({
          ...provided,
          backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? 'red' : 'white',
        }),
        multiValue: (provided, state) => ({
          ...provided,
          backgroundColor: "yellow",
          color: "black",
        }),
        multiValueLabel: (provided) => ({
          ...provided,
          color: "red",
        }),
      }; 

      const handleOptionSelect = (selected) => {
        setSelectedOption(selected);
      };
      
      return (
        <form>
          <h3 className='heading'>Jewish Music</h3>
          <div className='Image'></div>
          <label htmlFor="songName" className='formText'>Start your search</label>
          <Select
            options={songOptions}
            placeholder="Song name"
            components={{ Option: customOption }}
            styles={customStyles}
            isMulti
            value={selectedOption}
            onChange={handleOptionSelect}
            closeMenuOnSelect={false}
            hideSelectedOptions={false}
          />
          <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
        </form>
      );
      
  }
```

I attempted to modify the styling of selected options by adjusting the customStyles object within the react-select component. Specifically, I focused on the backgroundColor property to change the background color of selected items. I expected that this change would alter the appearance of the selected option backgrounds, highlighting them with a distinct color.
I didn't try to adjust the theme.